# Difference between 2 exe files

Tags: delphi, window

One exe file is system file, such as net.exe or sc.exe; one is downloaded like PsService.exe.
I found that One(net.exe or sc.exe) I can use it in a service via ShellExecute(); another cannot be used. what is different between them? any one knows?
simon

Comment: Well, they are different. They do different things. That's about it really.

Comment: What user is the service running as? If I recall correctly the "ps..." tools will display a license/disclaimer the first time they are ran under each user. Try running psservice.exe once interactively as the same user the service is running as, so you can acknowledge the disclaimer.

Comment: When you call PsServie.exe at the first time, it shows the other window, you have to accept. later it no longer display. it is in a windows' application run OK, but it doesn't work in the service application. I need to find why like that, how to call psservice.exe in a service. simon

Comment: Well, there's no interaction in a service. Try to read up on vista session 0 isolation?

Comment: the code: ShellExecute(0, nil, 'PsService.exe', 'start SCardSvr', 'c:\PsTools', SW_HIDE); just one line code, for this code if change PSservice.exe to sc, it can be used in a service application

Comment: @user3228662 It sure would help us if you show code ([in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26726584/edit)) and describe what you know of the executables.

Comment: You should use CreateProcess rather than ShellExecute to start new processes

Answer (score 0):

`net.exe` and `sc.exe` are system administration commands, and fire [UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if the current user session doesn't have administrative privileges. If you are trying to make changes to the system's configuration, please learn about [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) or the specific API for the sub-system (e.g. the [Windows Network Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) (as well as about administrative priviliges and how to obtain them).

Comment: What does "fire UAC" mean?

Comment: You know, when the screen goes black for a second, and then there's a pop-up that asks your permission (for something it never tells.) https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=UAC%20popup&tbs=imgo:1

Comment: That's the UAC elevation dialog. It doesn't show when you start sc or net. Try for yourself.